# Junit Test Error: No field 'segmentmask' found in class 'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap'

Tags: maven, junit, powermock, xstream, jboss-arquillian

Trying to run an Arquillian test with PowerMockRule in a Maven project to be able to mock static classes.

However, when I'm building the maven project, I get the following error in the test:

Tests in error:
    myTest(com.package.myTest): Could not call java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.readObject() : No field 'segmentmask' found in class 'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap'

I have no idea about the cause of this and how to go about fixing it. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Apparently the problem is caused by XStream class loader which is needed in using PowerMockRule. But I haven't found a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed caused by an x-stream issue (which is fixed in 1.4.8):
http://x-stream.github.io/jira/761/

So if you use maven for dependency managing you might want to do something like this in your dependency management:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Should be removed as soon as xstream is updated in powermock -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

And then where you use powermock:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Should be removed as soon as powermock has the latest version of xstream -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
  <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

At least, until powermock starts to use the new x-stream version.